# How to encrypt data from Firebase database owner

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, encryption, firebase-security

## My Website

I am developing a Website that uses Firebase Realtime database to store its data and function properly.
The website is a Quiz website where the users can build quizzes, which the database collects *with a set of correct options for the answers*. Now, whenever another user opens the website he opens the quiz and answers it after he clicks the submit button the correct options are accessed from the real-time database and are checked with his selected answers and the marks are sent to the database accordingly.

## The Problem

As mentioned above, the correct options are stored in the real-time database and can only be accessed when the quiz is submitted. The real catch is if the data is stored in the real-time database then the *Firebase account owner can still access it by ***just changing the server-side code or by changing the firebase database rules*** for once and then again reverting it back*. Actually, anyway I am also a user of the website so I don't want to leave anyway for me to see the answers before answering which would be an unethical practice.

## What I have done so far

- I have so far tried to set Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules from the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

- Tried to find some way to code the server side and prevent this behavior
  but didn't find any way to prevent the database owner from accessing the data from the real-time database.

## My expectations

No user including the owner of the firebase database could access the correct answers before submitting the quiz.

---

Now I am seeking some way to prevent anyone from accessing the correct answers without submitting the quiz.

Comment: If your server code can determine the correct answers then necessarily a server admin could figure them out too.

Comment: What should I do to prevent it, the server admin should not view the data or edit it.

Comment: I’m saying you can’t prevent it.